# passing 2d array to the function to change the value

Tags: c++, arrays, function

edit:
this is how my output when I input number

```cpp
Please enter the move: 
1
X--
---
---
Please enter the move: 
2
-X-
---
---
Please enter the move: 
3
--X
---
---
Please enter the move: 
4
---
X--
---
Please enter the move:
```

The change is not saved.

I'm trying to change the array using the function that input by a user. It does get the input but it doesn't affect anything to my array outside of the function.

I've tried all different approaches

`void (char *array[])` or `void(char array[][3])` or `void(char **array)`

None of them worked.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <random>

using std::string;
using std::getline;
using namespace ::std;

const string winningCases[8] = {"123","456","789","147","258","369","159","357"};


void make_board(char grid[3][3]){
  // some code which works
}

void print_board(char grid[3][3]){
  // some code which works
}

void enter_move(char grid[][3]){
    char humanMove;
    int num_humanMove;

    while(true){
        cout << "Please enter the move: " << endl;
        cin >> humanMove;

        // find index for a grid
        num_humanMove = static_cast<int>(humanMove) - 49;

        int row = num_humanMove / 3;
        int col = num_humanMove % 3;

        // check right input
        if(49 > static_cast<int>(humanMove) && static_cast<int>(humanMove) < 57){
            cout << "Not valid input. " << endl;

        }else if(grid[row][col] == 'X' || grid[row][col]== 'O'){
            cout << "It's taken. " << endl;

        }else{
            grid[row][col] = 'X';

//            print_board(*grid[3]);

            break;
        }
    }

}

int find_grid_space(char move){
  // some code which works
}

char continue_play(){
  // some code which works
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char grid[3][3];


    char play='y';
    bool win=true;
    while(play == 'y' || play == 'Y'){
        while(win){

            make_board(grid);
            print_board(grid);

            enter_move(grid);

            win = !check_for_win(grid);

        }
        play = continue_play();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, the function `void enter_move(char grid[][3])` should get the input from the user and change the grid. It changes the grid in the function but it won't do anything outside of the function.

Comment: No, that code works (I'm talking about `enter_move`). Whatever your problem is, it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: @Chipster It might be a duplicate, but the thing is that he's doing it right already.

Comment: @john fair point. Maybe should be closed for not being clear what isn't working about these solutions?

Comment: We see this all the time, newbie has a problem with some code, and thinks they know where the problem is. But often they are wrong. So it might help if you also posted why you think this code doesn't change `grid` outside the function. It's there that you've probably made your mistake, because `enter_move` looks fine.

Comment: Well it doesn’t work on my laptop.. would that be a problem too??

Comment: Have you tried debugging your programme? That should always be your first choice if you encounter trouble...

Comment: Try and see it from our point of view, so far you've posted some perfectly correct looking code and all you've said is 'it doesn't work'.

Comment: oh @john I'll stop just saying 'it doesn't work' haha so in my code, it doens't print out what it supposed to print. for example, when I put 1, it should print `1--\n---\n---` but it will only print `---\n---\n---`. I don't think it's other function's problem since these are using same `grid[3][3]`. I might be wrong.. more likely probably lol

Comment: OK, I'm going to take a guess at the problem, answer soon.

Comment: Note that your *check right input* does not seem correct

Comment: Shouldn't it print `X--\n---\n---\n`? You call `make_board` within your while loop – I'd guess that you overwrite the previously modified board this way. Suppose you should move the call to this function in front of the `while(win)` loop.

Comment: @Aconcagua Geez.. you're right. I feel so stupid. Ok, so `make_board` was in a second `while` loop and it did overwrite my board. I moved that to the first `while` loop and problem solved. Thank you and sorry everyone who was trying to help.

Comment: @Damien hmm how not correct?

Comment: I guess you want to check if the input is not  in a given range, 49-56, it is not what you are doing

Comment: Are you aware that you can use character literals for comparison? `if('1' <= x && x <= '9') { /*correct input */ }`? That would be safe even on systems not using ASCII-compatible encoding ('0' ... '9' are guaranteed to be subsequent by C-standard – which doesn't apply for other symbols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be here

```
   while(win){
        make_board(grid);
        print_board(grid);
        enter_move(grid);
        win = !check_for_win(grid);
    }
```

Each time round the loop you call `make_board` which I'm **guessing** resets the board each time.

What you should have is this

```
   make_board(grid);
   while(win){
        print_board(grid);
        enter_move(grid);
        win = !check_for_win(grid);
    }
```

so that you only set up the board once.

Comment: Which proves the problem was not where the OP thought it was :D

Comment: Yes it looks like a text book example.

Comment: My duplicate was a duplicate of the title. I hate when questions aren't what they say they are.

Comment: @KatYang No worries. It's really not a big deal.